# What does draw the vector space of a system mean?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations:

[image]

The problem I have to solve is the following:

Draw the vector space of the system using matlab in a rectangle containing the stationary points.For $t\in[0,10]$ make animation of the movement of the point $(x(t),y(t))$ which at time $t=0$ starts from point $(x_1,y_1)$ which is enetered with the mouse by clicking in on the rectangle.

What does draw the vector space mean? Does it mean I have to solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$  and then draw the graphic?

Answer (score 1):

The topic you want to known is called [phase portrait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_portrait).

See for instance this [post](http://matlab.cheme.cmu.edu/2011/08/09/phase-portraits-of-a-system-of-odes//) about phase portrait of ODEs with MATLAB$^®$.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jack, you will want to plot a phase portrait for the dynamical system.

If you are not required to write the program yourself, then consider getting the program PPLANE.

You can find the program here:

- [PPLANE for MATLAB](http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/index.html) (assuming you have access to MATLAB)
- [PPLANE for Java](http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/dfpp.html) (if you do not have access to MATLAB)